# Google lighthouse audit report throws error: Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page that you requested. (Status code: 404)

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse

When I try after my site migration to cloud, I see no audit stats but following error.
How can I correct it? So that I can generate reports and can compare against the baseline I've taken much before the migration.

**"Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page that you requested. Make sure that you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 404)"**

Comment: well 404 is pretty straight forward, the URL is wrong somewhere. Have you changed the URL - perhaps you haven't set up redirects from http to https correctly or something. At the moment we can't really help as there is no debug info so can only offer guesses, do you want to share the URL you are trying to test in the comments.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie -  url, api's and the site are functioning perfectly ok. There is no 404 in normal mode. This 404 error is faced just on light house auditing mode.